# Sconfig 0.00000 tap: on snoop: rts? on errs? on

Tags: tcl, ns2, tr

I am working on a project in Mobile Ad Hoc Network(MANET) ,using ns.35 and  when executing this code using DSR

```
# Define options
set val(chan)           Channel/WirelessChannel    ;# channel type
set val(prop)           Propagation/TwoRayGround   ;# radio-propagation model
set val(netif)          Phy/WirelessPhy            ;# network interface type
set val(mac)            Mac/802_11                 ;# MAC type
set val(ifq)            CMUPriQueue             ;# interface queue type
set val(ll)             LL                         ;# link layer type
set val(ant)            Antenna/OmniAntenna        ;# antenna model
set val(ifqlen)         100000                         ;# max packet in ifq
set val(nn)             38                         ;# number of mobilenodes
set val(rp)             DSR                       ;# routing protocol
set val(x)              800                ;# X dimension of topography
set val(y)              800                ;# Y dimension of topography 
set val(seed)           0.0
set val(cp)             "cbrNCR"
set val(sc)             "set38"
set val(stop)       200.0              ;# time of simulation end

set ns_       [new Simulator]
set tracefile       [open DSR.tr w]
#set windowVsTime2 [open win.tr w] 

$ns_ trace-all $tracefile
$ns_ use-newtrace 
#$ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace $val(x) $val(y)

# set up topography object
set topo       [new Topography]

$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)
#Open the NAM trace file
set namfile [open manet.nam w]
$ns_ namtrace-all $namfile
$ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namfile $val(x) $val(y)


set god_ [create-god $val(nn)]
set chan_1_ [new $val(chan)]
#
#  Create nn mobilenodes [$val(nn)] and attach them to the channel. 
#

# configure the nodes
        $ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
             -llType $val(ll) \
             -macType $val(mac) \
             -ifqType $val(ifq) \
             -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
             -antType $val(ant) \
             -propType $val(prop) \
             -phyType $val(netif) \
             -channel $chan_1_ \
             -topoInstance $topo \
             -agentTrace ON \
             -routerTrace ON \
             -macTrace ON \
-energyModel "EnergyModel" \
        -initialEnergy 100.0 \
        -txPower 2.0522 \
        -rxPower 0.0591 \
        -idlePower 0.00006 \
        -sleepPower 0.000003 \


            
             
    for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } { incr i } {
        set node_($i) [$ns_ node]
                $node_($i) random-motion 0  ;# disable random motion
    }

puts "Loading connection pattern..."
source $val(cp)

puts "Loading scenario file..."
source $val(sc)
proc finish {} {
    global ns_ tracefile namfile
    $ns_ flush-trace
    close $tracefile
    close $namfile
    exec nam manet.nam &
    exit 0
}

 for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
    $ns_ initial_node_pos $node_($i) 20
}
 
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
    $ns_ at $val(stop).000000001 "$node_($i) reset";
}
$ns_ at $val(stop) "$ns_ nam-end-wireless $val(stop)"
$ns_ at $val(stop).000000001 "puts \"NS EXITING...\"; $ns_ halt"
puts "Start Simulation..."
$ns_ run
```

it shows me that in tr file.. Why ?  How can it be handled?

Sconfig 0.00000 tap: on snoop: rts? on errs? on
Sconfig 0.00000 salvage: on !bd replies? on
Sconfig 0.00000 grat error: on grat reply: on
Sconfig 0.00000 $reply for props: on ring 0 search: on
Sconfig 0.00000 using MOBICACHE

Comment: Sconfig is a setting. The trace lines tell which Sconfig's are on. ... See `Sconfig.jpg`, etc. trace doc  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1X_SaZcTYF2tI5XGVClImBvAZY1_QOrDj?usp=sharing                   (  NS2 doc is disappearing from the Net these years.  )

Answer (score 0):

Sconfig is a DSR setting. The trace lines tell which Sconfig's are on. ... Please see Sconfig.jpg, etc. trace doc https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1X_SaZcTYF2tI5XGVClImBvAZY1_QOrDj?usp=sharing

Sconfig.jpg shows a snippet from 'NS-2 Trace Formats - nsnam.html' = NS-2_TraceFormats-nsnam.html

```
$ cd ns-2.35
$ grep -nR Sconfig *
dsr/dsragent.cc:468:  trace("Sconfig %.5f tap: %s snoop: rts? %s errs? %s",
dsr/dsragent.cc:473:  trace("Sconfig %.5f salvage: %s !bd replies? %s",
dsr/dsragent.cc:477:  trace("Sconfig %.5f grat error: %s grat reply: %s",
dsr/dsragent.cc:481:  trace("Sconfig %.5f $reply for props: %s ring 0 search: %s",
dsr/linkcache.cc:309:   trace("Sconfig %.5f using LINKCACHE %d", Scheduler::instance().clock(),
dsr/mobicache.cc:209:   trace("Sconfig %.5f using MOBICACHE", Scheduler::instance().clock());
dsr/simplecache.cc:204: trace("Sconfig %.5f using MOBICACHE", Scheduler::instance().clock());
```

Which means `grep` has searched ns2, all directories and all sub directories for the word `Sconfig`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, but I don't understand what to do now?

Comment: To do with what ? .......... All DSR simulations will show similar information in the trace file.tr https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xmJ8GwGuFGTo2zVpWoE1QdngVAjuFknc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

When I use this code
$ cd ns-2.35
$grep -nR Sconfig *.
The following appears:

```
dsr/simplecache.cc:204: trace("Sconfig %.5f using MOBICACHE", Scheduler::instance().clock());
Binary file dsr/mobicache.o matches
dsr/linkcache.cc:309:   trace("Sconfig %.5f using LINKCACHE %d", Scheduler::instance().clock(),
dsr/dsragent.cc:468:  trace("Sconfig %.5f tap: %s snoop: rts? %s errs? %s",
dsr/dsragent.cc:473:  trace("Sconfig %.5f salvage: %s !bd replies? %s",
dsr/dsragent.cc:477:  trace("Sconfig %.5f grat error: %s grat reply: %s",
dsr/dsragent.cc:481:  trace("Sconfig %.5f $reply for props: %s ring 0 search: %s",
Binary file dsr/dsragent.o matches
dsr/mobicache.cc:209:   trace("Sconfig %.5f using MOBICACHE", Scheduler::instance().clock());
Binary file ns matches
Binary file nstk matches
```

Comment: Of course any code / any information is compiled into objects, and to executable.

Comment: I have another question, please, how to extract the number of requests and reply for each node when using the DSR protocol